# Google Sheets - Workaround for REPT character limit of 32000

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to repeat a range of values (text), `A2:A19` by `G2:G19` number of times. However, one of the repetitions has higher 'n' value and therefore no repetitions shows up for that particular text value because `REPT` result cannot exceed the limit of 32000 characters.

```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(A2:A19&",",G2:G19 ), ,999^99), ","))))
```

Is there any tweak for this as I have tried multiple ways.

Comment: can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to `REPT` it by force indirectly:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(REPT("¤×", G2:G), "×")="",,A2:A))), 
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: @player0 figured you might like mine too :)

Comment: @MattKing indeed :)

Comment: It throws an error when the repetitive value is more than 16,000.
Error: Query completed with an empty output

Comment: This solution solved my question just before I posted it !  Thanks, @player0 !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different, non-text way to solve these problems so you avoid characters altogether:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(B2:B20&"|"&C2:C20&"|"&SEQUENCE(1,MAX(C2:C))),"|",0,0),"select Col1 where Col3<=Col2"))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1otGpKhNtATGeZM4V5hdP4sevezCt5D6jjFdtPJUOmJY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: For larger repetitions such as 40K+ the formula throws: "The resulting array was too large."